# How to redirect the output of a running process to a log file?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, redirection, prompt, logfiles

When running a long running task in a command prompt, it's possible to redirect the output to a log file (fe for storage or later analysis).

However, I started a few long running tasks this evening which were taking a lot longer than expected, and I cannot let my computer stay on overnight (company policy).

So I was wondering if there was a way to redirect the output of a running process to a logfile in Windows (in my case Windows 10 Enterprise to be exact).

Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Marlon

Comment: How about running the command and add >C:\folderpath at the end of the command?

Comment: @ottowang Thanks for your reply, but this can only be done when you start the command. As I mentioned in my question, I already started the tasks. My question is how to do the same for an already running process.